# How can I ensure that a particular .dylib is loaded first by dyld?

Tags: ios, startup, dyld

I want to load a small .dylib before any other others are loaded, so that I can measure the current time at that moment to understand how long the other dylibs are taking to load. How can I do this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but dyld itself can collect information about how long various dylibs take to load. Set `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS_DETAILS=1` in the environment to see details.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that I want to collect this data for users in the wild.